# What will happen if i remove visual compsoser tool from my wordpress site after building the site using it?

Tags: wordpress, frontend

I am Modifying a WordPress site for a client. The previous developer who built the site has used visual composer to build it. Now, as I modify the site I find it difficult to add my codes and do my modification since I am not a visual composer user. 
What will happen if I remove the visual composer from the site? Will I lose all the things built using visual composer

Comment: Probably yes, coz VC those page wont get the css and js so will look ugaly. and  Why not try it locally? make a copy of the website locally and then play with it. and **this question should be asked over here**.

Answer (score 1):

It will happen  that on pages built with vc you will see visual composer code instead of page elements like images, buttons and text you entered with the visual composer. But you won't lose the elements. If then you reinstall vc they will still be there and your page will show as you designed.